# app transport security has blocked a cleartext http resource load since it is insecure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios9

Though I followed [App Transport Security Technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html) and [Configuring App Transport Security Exceptions in iOS 9 and OSX 10.11](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) still I'm getting this error in iOS 9 **ERROR:App transport security has blocked a cleartext http resource load since it is insecure**

Comment: Did you add domain exceptions in your info.plist?

Answer (score 3):

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

just paste this code in plist

Comment: I'm getting this error but only when I attempt to test on an iPhone. If I simulate I do not get an error.

Comment: Because iphone be ios9 and simulator ios8

Comment: Thanks ... I had not noticed that.

Comment: feel free  to accept answer if it really hepl!
Happy coding